# A-Frame: Scaling a-box in EventListener: "this.el is undefined"

Tags: javascript, aframe

I want to setup an EventListener in A-Frame (JS) that listens to the 'mouseenter'-event and rescales a box. I took the source from [this tutorial](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/guides/building-a-basic-scene.html#event-listener-component-intermediate). The EventListener fires every time I move the cursor on the box, but then the console shows

```
TypeError: this.el is undefined
```

referencing to this line of code:

```
this.el.object3D.scale.copy(data.to);
```

This is the code:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('scale-on-mouseenter', {
    schema: {
      to: {default: '10 10 10', type: 'vec3'}
    },

    init: function () {
      var data = this.data;
      this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
        this.el.object3D.scale.copy(data.to);
      });
    }
  });
</script>
...
 <a-box position="0 2 -5" scale-on-mouseenter>
 </a-box>
```

It also says:

```
core:schema:warn Default value `10 10 10` does not match type `vec3` in component `scale-on-mouseenter`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `this.el is undefined`.

This is a matter of [scope](https://javascriptplayground.com/javascript-variable-scope-this/). `this` does not refer to the same object:

```
//....
init: function() {
// here this refers the component object
console.log(this) 
this.el.addEventListener('event', function() {
    // here this refers to this.el (as the object which has the listener added)
    console.log(this)
//...
```

---

You create a variable refering to the data object, you could do the same with `this.el`:

```
var el = this.el;
this.el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    el.doSomething();
```

or use a lambda, which does not change the scope:

```
this.el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    this.el.doSomething();
```

2) `value does not match type`

`vec3` expects a vector: `{x: 10, y: 10, z: 10}` instead of a string `10 10 10`